# Getting translation text from Google Translate [HTML]

Tags: html, google-translate

I am developing an application where I have a free-text object for the user to add some comments.

After SUBMIT button is clicked, I sent this info to a DB.

My question is: can I use Google Translate to translate this text before sending it to the DB?

For example, if I enter "This is a test" and I want to translate into Dutch, I can use this link:

```
http://translate.google.com/#en/nl/This%20is%20a%20test
```

But I don't know how to get this value back from translate.google.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want the google translate API [it is not free](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/pricing)

Comment: Thanks Liam for your answer. I didn't know it was paid... I am thinking about a new solution. I've asked in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22222770/html-concatenating-text-input-with-link.